# Как вы нашли работу?

Tags: работа

Я вот-вот получу диплом бакалавра и уже хочется не штаны просиживать в аудиториях, а какой-то практический опыт получать. Как вы нашли свою первую работу?

Comment: А на кого Вы учились и чем хотите заниматься?

Comment: Учусь на специальности, которая осталась с советских времен и готовит специалистов в области компьютерных наук. А работать планирую Java-программистом.

Comment: Так вы говорите, Java хотите заниматься.. у вас есть какие-то скилы уже или хотите на ходу разбираться?

Comment: Думаю на среднем уровне Java я знаю. Просто нет опыта практической разработки серьезных проектов. В свое время серьезно изучал Swing и Java2D, даже есть несколько наработок в этой области. Жаль эти технологии сейчас не сильно востребованы. Сейчас изучаю Java для Web, так как понимаю, что реальные деньги только там.

Comment: Продолжайте учиться и начинайте поднимать нашу науку.

Comment: Ответы собрать - и 2-й том http://codersatwork.com/ получится

Comment: какой сайт ?

Comment: Защитил чтобы не публиковали новые ответы, а не потому что вопрос хороший (он плохой).

Answer (score 65):

Так же как и многие другие. В конце второго курса написал резюме и послал в кучу мест. Много где меня послали куда подальше, так как опыта работы не было и режим работы мой был неясный.. но в одном месте взяли. И понеслась :)

Comment: Вот прям так и чешутся руки написать "+1" =)))

Comment: Аналогично)

Comment: ну +1, что тут сказать :)

Comment: Мы что, такие одинаковые?) Мне вообще работа понравилась и я из универа ушел на третьем. Надо сказать, не жалею - экспы нахватал, хотя и не советую - нервов уйму сжег, как котенок в джунглях пробивался.

Comment: Хе-хе. Вообще, я всегда говорю всем (но некоторые не верят мне): если работа не приносит радость и удовольствие, то это плохая работа и надо немедленно увольняться :)

Comment: Все же зависит от человека, если он не привык трудиться то и удовольствие врят ли будет получать от труда :-)

Comment: Тут я бы поспорил, все зависит от размера зп, как мне кажется. Если работа, которая приносит тебе радость, оплачивается, скажем в 30к, а работа, которая просто приносит тебе деньги, оплачивается в 100к, то глупо ее менять :)

Comment: Но если разница в деньгах не так велика.. то можеи и не стоит..

Comment: а я не работаю, я пишу код, я занимаюсь своим любимым делом, а мне в добавок еще и деньги платят =)))

Answer (score 10):

Поздно спохватились конечно. Теперь главное адекватно понимать свои возможности. Не гнаться за большой зарплатой Идти туда, где сможете набраться опыта. Сейчас для вас главное не зарплата, а опыт.

Comment: Думаете 4-й курс уже поздно?

Comment: Ах да... Четвертый курс. Я почему-то подумал, что Вы заканчиваете уже. Тогда самое время.

Comment: Вообще можно продолжить обучение в университете и заниматься какими-нибудь исследовательскими проектами :-) Один из способов приобретения опыта :-)

Comment: Если заниматься исследовательской работой, то оч. много зависит от ВУЗа и руководителя. Я, например, со второго курса устроился работать в исследовательский институт. К окончанию универа у меня было три года опыта. Поработав полгода после универа в коммерческой организации понял, что маялся дурью. Ну может и не дурью, но мог бы провести время с большей пользой. К сожалению уровень науки в РФ по большей части оставляет желать лучшего.

Answer (score 10):

Когда я ещё не был программистом (по первому образованию я агрохимик), я вообще листовки в пробках раздавал. Первый раз устроился работать программистом под конец магистратуры, когда заканчивал соответствующую переподготовку. Впечатления такие: поначалу проще устроиться туда, где занимаются какой-нибудь экзотикой и готовы ей обучать.

Answer (score 7):

А я вот на 3 курсе подрабатывал в разных компаниях тестировщиком ПО,
потом год не работал.
Полноценно, на постоянной основе стал трудиться только на 5 курсе
устроившись на кафедру,теперь вот 3-ий год на Java программирую.
Должен сказать что поднабрался опыта - спасибо родному электротехническому университету.

Теперь остался в аспирантуре. Пошли интересные исследовательские проекты.

---

P.S.
Зря некоторые критикуют Российскую науку ведь всё зависит от нас самих.
По мне так лучше в российской организации работать, т.к. на дядю Сема
трудиться слишком много желающих. 
А кто о своей собственной стране думать будет если не мы?

Comment: Поддерживаю, я сейчас ещё учусь и при этом работаю в лаборатории, задания очень интересные.

Answer (score 4):

Разослал ссылки на свою страницу на LinkedIn. Через 3 собеседования устроился на работу которая меня устраивала.

Answer (score 3):

Я вобще поздно спохватилась. Закончила универ и тогда только начала искать работу. Полгода металась с одного места на другое: везде заключала договора. Если что-то не устраивало - тут же начинала искать работу снова. Особого выбора, правда, не было: куда брали, туда и шла. Таким макаром побывала продавцом-консультантом в компьютерном отделе и программистом на нескольких предприятиях. Хотелось программировать, но обычно под словом "программист" работодатель подразумевал одмина-эникейщика. А то бывало и сразу отказывали либо из-а того, что нету опыта, либо вовсе из-за того, что я девушка). И так продолжалось, пока не нашла работу по душе. Теперь тружусь веб-программистом и очень рада, что нашла эту работу. Наверное, не часто человек может похвастаться, что ему нравится ходить на работу и он там занимается любимым делом))

Comment: **zyxel** 
:))) Гы, я тоже могу похвастаться :))) ...

Comment: @zyxel обычно программисты как раз хвастаются этим :)

Answer (score 3):

Я начал работать на 2м курсе, на 3м был уже на постоянной основе. В последнее время правда уже скорее ищут меня чем ищу я, но это выстрадано долгим построением репутации.

Answer (score 2):

:))) 
17 лет - Лето на дворе - жара...Рещил пойти на работу работать, но куда - не знал :)))
И тут открыл сайт местного провайдера где черным по Русскому было написано "Срочно требуется работник в ТП".
Труда пройти собеседование не составило (я на то время был админ нашей Дом. сетки, так что то, что у меня спрашивали - мне было знакомо).....
Оттуда и все понеслось :)

Comment: А что такое ТП? Неужели они самые? (Привет лурк)

Answer (score 2):

Я получил работу когда был второй раз на 1м курсе. В группе выдали анкеты, я сразу понял по вопросам для чего она. Таким образом я стал сисадмином на кафедре, через пол года это стало моей официальной работой с зарплатой.

Answer (score 2):

Пошел на собеседование в 1С и веб-студию. В первой предложили бесплатное обучение, с последующим трудоустройством. В веб-студии: работу )
Так вот стал веб-разработчиком.

Answer (score 2):

Первая моя работа тоже была поздно, после окончания универа. Немаленькая организация, неплохая зарплата, неплохое занятие. Но и вправду говорится, что работа должна приносить удовольствие, ну или хотя бы удовлетворение. Неплохая оплата не смогла компенсировать скуку и стресс. В итоге через полгода новая работа: программирование под iOS. Устраивает все, кроме зарплаты. Но так получилось, что моральное удовлетворение важнее зарплаты :) В университете было заблуждение, что не важно, какая работа, главное, чтобы хорошо платили...

Answer (score 2):

Получил работу на втором курсе. На кафедре порекомендовали меня в информационный отдел, после чего я устроился там работать. Сначала на маленькую з/п для опыта, лаборантом. Потом поднялся до ведущего программиста, опыт набрал неплохой для того времени.

Answer (score 2):

Написал прогу - некий аналог ГИСа, увидели какие-то буржуины - пригласили к себе и понеслось...

Answer (score 2):

Так получилось, что компьютер у меня дома появился еще в конце 80-х (отец был программистом в каком-то сверхсекретном НИИ, но ему удалось принести домой "списанный" ЕС-1840), когда понятие компьютер (да и ЭВМ) было незнакомо народу, да и вообще не вызывало никакого интереса у одноклассников и друзей. С него началось изучение ДОС, Бейсика и Паскаля. Потом были тяжелые годы, связанные с переделом СССР, годы бесперспективности и застоя. Уже учась в институте, начал подрабатывать на складе в фешенебельном ресторане - зарабатывал свои деньги, но самое главное - получил бесценный опят работы в коллективе, научился делопроизводству, ответственности, несмотря на то, что профессия была далеко не той, о которой мечтал. Все эти годы компьютер был рядом со мной дома (уже не ЕС-1840) и я довольно много времени уделял обучению и практике, хотя даже в те времена бухгалтерия ресторана обходилась без компьютера, и лишь потом директор принес первый в истории DX486-ой с Windows 95, который поручили мне, чтобы обучить бухгалтера работать с Excel.

Так получилось, что мне посчастливилось познакомиться с мои ровесником, который работал в рекламном агентстве, куда я был принят. Спустя полгода я уже профессионально работал в Corel и имел свои собственные работы в виде плакатов и 3D-инсталляций, развешанных по городу, а также брошюр и прочей рекламной атрибутики. Но с рисованием и дизайном я не дружил с детства, поэтому я знал, что это не моя сфера, где я был сугубо техническим исполнителем, но никак не креативным работником. Забыл упомянуть: я всегда увлекался электроникой и радиотехникой. Поэтому однажды подал свое резюме в компанию Ericsson, был вызван на собеседование, но принят не был (какой-то иностранец почему-то спросил меня, знаю ли я С++, хотя, как позже выяснилось, это не имело отношения к работе вообще, а будущие коллеги впоследствии сказали, что спросить это у меня его подтолкнул тот факт, что у одного из сотрудников на столе лежала книга по С++, которую этот иностранец принял за учебник технологии, которая якобы использовалась в их офисе). Спустя год я опять повторил попытку, прошел собеседование с другим уже начальством и был принят. Ericsson обслуживал местного оператора мобильной связи, но спустя пару лет, после реформирования контракта между компаниями, я с несколькими сотрудниками перешли работать в саму компанию - мобильный оператор, где и работаю на сегодняшний день уже более 10-ти лет.

Вот такая вот история со получением работы. Я считаю, что если хотеть - то добиться можно всего. Главное - не опускать руки и учиться, учиться и еще раз учиться.

Answer (score 1):

На 3-ем курсе пришел дядька с фирмы, спросил кому нужна работа, прошел собеседование у него, так и устроился на программиста )

Comment: интересный, актуальный, а главное, уникальный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Взломал "Счастливого фермера" Вконтакте и понеслось....увлекся web программированием и web дизайном. В данный момент помогаю своему учебному заведению с сайтом. - "Работа за уважение":)

Answer (score -1):

Курсе на 3-ем, одногруппник предложил сверстать дизайн и подработать. В то время я ничего об этом не знал. Ну и понеслось :) 
Через зарубежную биржу труда вышел на заказчика из своего города, который после разовых работ, пригласил к себе в веб-студию.

Answer (score -1):

Нашёл свою первую работу на 3-м курсе. 
До этого изучал java и android , пытался писать свои приложения.
Друг уже устроился летом iOS разработчиком и пригласил меня. В итоге успешно выполнив задание я стал работать android разработчиком.

Answer (score -1):

Студент, в конце первого курса заполнил резюмешку на сайте вакансий, и все теперь работаю, получаю опыт ( веб разработка ) =)

Answer (score -2):

В начале первого курса института пошел на собеседование на android developer и прошел, так как я после техникума у меня диплом младшего специалиста и соответственно 20 лет за плечами) до этого интересовался разработкой под дроид и когда пришел на собеседование без проблем ответил на вопросы и прошел.